# How to set up TrueCrypt "traveler disk" using Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, usb, truecrypt

I managed to encode my USB device having installed TrueCrypt on my Mac. I want to use the device with other Windows/OS X computers that may not have a version of TrueCrypt installed.

How do I get my USB to have the traveler disk setup that seems to be easily achievable through Windows, but apparently only there?

Comment: Related: [How to create a cross-platform traveler disk with TrueCrypt](http://superuser.com/questions/615481/how-to-create-a-cross-platform-traveler-disk-with-truecrypt).

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion:

- Partition the USB stick, one partition to be encrypted, and one not (ensure the 2nd partition is of a format that can be read by target machines).
- Put the data on the partition you encrypt, encrypt it with TrueCrypt.
- Put the TrueCrypt installer(s) in the unencrypted partition.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But then I still need to install true crypt on every device through which I want to access the encrypted partition on the USB - don't I?